# Spring JPA Sorting and Paging with PostgreSQL JSONB

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I am using Spring JPA in order to manage my PostgreSQL data. This data makes heavy use of the `jsonb` data type in PostgreSQL `9.4`.

My table (called `jobtable`), simplified looks something like this:

```
id, bigint | data, jsonb
--------------------------------
1          | {"name": "Hello"}
2          | {"name": "Testing"}
```

Using Spring JPA, I am defining a `CrudRepository` interface in order to make some queries for this table. For `jsonb` specific things, I am using `nativeQuery = true` so that I can make use of this PostgreSQL type.

For example, I can query my property like so:

```
@Query(
 value = "select * from jobtable where data ->> 'name' = ?1",
 nativeQuery = true)
JobEntity getJobByName(String name);
```

This query works just fine.

My problem occurs when I try to use Pagination with native queries using `jsonb`. My query is as such:

```
@Query(
 value = "select * from jobtable \n#pageable\n", 
 countQuery = "select count(*) from jobtable", 
 nativeQuery = true)
Page<JobEntity> getJobList(Pageable pageable);
```

I include the `Pageable` parameter and call the function as such:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10, Direction.DESC, "data ->> 'name'");
Page<JobEntity> results = myDao.getJobList(pageable);
```

This code does not work, and produces the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
 Sort expression 'data ->> 'name': DESC' must only contain property references or aliases used in the select clause. If you really want to use something other than that for sorting, please use JpaSort.unsafe(â€¦)!
```

I am not sure what to make of this error. I think it has to do with improperly understanding my `sortBy` parameter in the `PageRequest` object, but I am not sure how else to structure that `PageRequest` object when I am intending to sort on a key within my `jsonb` object.

I can construct Raw SQL to PostgreSQL that looks something like `select * from job order by data ->> 'jobId' desc limit 10` but I would rather use the `Pageable` interface with Spring JPA so that I can use the `@Query` notation and not have to define anything explicitly in code myself.

Comment: thanks for asking this question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to create the Pageable as follows:

```
Pageable p = PageRequest.of(1,10,
            JpaSort.unsafe(Direction.DESC, "data->>'name'"));
```

This should get rid of the exception.

Comment: Doesn't help on Spring 5+

Comment: JpaSort.unsafe(sortDirection, jsonb_extract_path(jsonbColumnName, 'jsonbField'))

Answer (score 3):

For those finding this question where you are using the org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification here is how I was able to get it to work inside of the toPredicate method

```
Expression exp = criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", 
    String.class, 
    root.get("data"), 
    criteriaBuilder.literal("name"));

switch (direction){
    case ASC:
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(exp));
        break;
    case DESC:
    default:
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(exp));
        break;

}
```